# Why isn't this script working?

Tags: javascript, html

I put this into Notepad and saved as an htm.  However, when I open it in IE, it just says the text without the `<HEAD>` and `</HEAD>`.  I have tried encoding it as Unicode, UTF-8, Unicode big Endian, and ANSI.:

```
<HEAD>
var ifbumper=0
if (ifbumper=0)
  {
  window.location='/bumper?url=whatever'
  }
</HEAD>
```

Answer (score 4):

You're writing JavaScript code, you need to put it inside of `<script>` tags. You also need to use `==` instead of `=` to compare values, and it's a good idea to put a `;` following a line of code.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT>
    var ifbumper=0;
    if (ifbumper==0)
    {
        window.location='/bumper?url=whatever';
    }
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
```

Comment: Better also specify `type` attribute and have it lower case.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard the "type" attribute is not necessary anymore unless for some reason you're (making the mistake of) using XHTML :-) It's really only useful when you explicitly want the browser *not* to interpret the contents of the `<script>` block, like for use with template systems. Otherwise, it's just a potential source for nasty bugs.

Comment: @Pointy you mean in HTML5, or any version of HTML?

Comment: @Shadow HTML5 is largely based on how browsers actually behave; browsers will execute `<script>` tags without `type`s in any version of HTML, even if it is required in the spec. (It might fail in XHTML, I'm not sure.)

Comment: @hidividedby5 If this fixed your problem, you can press the grey checkbox on the left of this post to "accept" it as the solution to your problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap JavaScript code inside `<script>` tags like this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ifbumper = 0;
        if (ifbumper == 0){
            window.location='/bumper?url=whatever';
        }
     </script>
</head>
```

Comment: When I try to test it, it says: To help protect your security, Internet Explorer has restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls that could access your computer. Click here for options...  Is there any way to make the script so it doesn't show this? (P.S. I'm running this from my computer if that makes any difference.)

Answer (score 0):

The equality operator is ==, not just =. Your if should be a`if (ifbumper == 0)`

Comment: True but not relevant to the question.